# How can I add a video to my page if i'm using asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html5-video

I have a project in asp.net and I'm trying to add an html5 video with a src referencing a video I have in the solution.

Here is the relevant code for index.cshtml where I'm trying to add the video:

```
<video class="uk-cover-object" id="timelapseVideo">
    <source src="~/videos/landing.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

and this is the file structure:

```
-Project
  -AppData
  -AppStart
  -Content
  -videos
    -landing.mp4
  -views
    -home
      -index.cshtml
```

I've done this before in a nodejs project and it works fine but I'm fairly new to asp and not exactly sure why the video isn't being exposed to the front end. I've also tried placing the video in the content folder and same result. Any help would be much appreciated!

Using ASP 4. Html5 video with a youtube link as the source doesn't work either.

Comment: To get better answers it wouldn't hurt to be more specific about what version of ASP.net you are using

Answer (score 0):

If the path to video is correct (you could check by displaying an image in the same folder) then this might be a MIME setting issue (server needs to be configured to allow serving files of specific types).

Also try Google: "ASP.net (your version) video files".

[How to play video files using asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1409628.aspx?How%20to%20play%20video%20files%20using%20asp%20net)

[How to enable IIS to play MP4 files](http://forums.asp.net/t/1470612.aspx?How%20to%20enable%20IIS%20to%20play%20MP4%20files)

Comment: I'm using ASP 4, and pictures are working fine. The path also seems to be correct.

Comment: What server are you using IIS?

Comment: Yep. I'm using IIS

Comment: Check the updated answer. You need to set IIS to allow video/mp4.

Comment: I had read that link when you mentioned IIS, it asks me to find the website i need to change settings for but it doesn't show up for me. Honestly, this should not be so hard and feels like a shortcoming, coming from nodejs to this. I found a jquery extension that might solve the issue so i'll probably just go with that.

Comment: I doubt that you can fool IIS's security feature with a client side script. Real production / professional servers like IIS or Apache need to be configured in order to work the way you want them to. Did you find the answer useful?